# How are the table data stored when it has a clustered index

Tags: sql, indexing, clustered-index

I have found umpteen posts which begin like **Quite a lot of time I have come across people saying "Clustered Index Physically sorts the data inside the table based on the Clustered Index Keys". It's not true!** Then such posts go on to describe how it is actually stored, via linked lists or whatever. For example, this [post](http://sqlwithmanoj.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/clustered-vs-nonclustered-indexes-and-data-sorting/) says that

> Each Index row contains a Key value and a pointer to either an
>   Intermediate level page in the B-tree, or a Data row in the Leaf level
>   of the Index. The Pages in each level of the Index are linked in a
>   Doubly-linked list. The Pages in the Data chain and the rows in them
>   are ordered on the value of the Clustered Index key.

That brings me to my question, the data pages *are* the place where the table data are stored, right? So if they are sorted and the data within them also are sorted according to the indexed column value, why is it wrong to say that the clustered index keeps the table data in sorted order? Here is a pic from Kalen Delaney's book, which shows that the leaf pages in a table with CI are all sorted according to the CI value:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right.

Clustered indexes do **not** physically sort the data inside the table based on the Clustered Index Keys. If that was the case then the inserts into the middle of a large table with no free space would require huge amounts of IO to make room for the new record.

Instead a new page is allocated from anywhere in the file and linked into the linked list.

The degree to which the physical order of pages differs from the logical order is the extent of logical fragmentation. Rebuilding or reorganizing the index can reduce this.

Comment: So doesn't that mean that there will be two copies of the same data, one in sorted order in the B-Tree and another in order of insertion in the actual table?

Comment: @Cupidvogel - No because the leaf level pages of the clustered index contain the rows of the table. There is only one copy.

Comment: Then how com the table is not physically sorted? If the leaf level pages are themselves sorted, and they contain th rows of the tables, then the tables have to be sorted too, right?

Comment: The leaf level pages **aren't** necessarily sorted. They are only fully sorted if there is zero logical fagmenation.

Comment: Ummm, then what exactly are sorted, if neither the leaf level pages, nor the table itself is?

Comment: Nothing. The leaf level pages **is** the table. They are not two distinct things. They are held in a linked list which may or may not be sorted. The degree to which the pages are out of order is the degree of fragmentation. It is possible for the linked list to progress (say) from pages `100 -> 101 -> 102` in which case there is zero fragmentation or it may progress from pages `100 -> 200 -> 150` in which case there is 100% fragmentation.

Comment: So basically one leaf level page holds a pointer to the next leaf, right? Then how come it is different from non-clustered index on a heap? In both cases, it seems that after coming to the leaf page, there has to be another indirection to the actual data. All books mention that for a clustered index, the **leaf is the data**, hence that indirection is spared, leading to faster data access.

Comment: The leaf level of the NCI only contains the data for columns defined in the index either as a key column or an included column. The leaf level of the CI contains data for all columns. (Ignoring wide tables with content stored off row). An NCI with `INCLUDE`-d columns of the whole table is almost the same structure as a CI.

Comment: So the only difference between these two is the data they contain, one contains only the index key value, the other contains the entire row (including the index key as well)? So if we define a non-clustered index with say 3 columns, and a particular query requires only those 3 columns (kind of like a covering index), a clustered index on those 3 columns (in a separate instance) will yield identical performance?

Comment: @Cupidvogel - You **can't** create a clustered index on only those 3 columns  (except if they are the only columns in the table) as a CI will implicitly `include` all other columns.

Comment: Ok, then for the NCI with those 3 columns covered as per the query, and a CI on one of those 3 columns will give the same performance?

Comment: By the way, although you said that leaf pages are not sorted, I have edited the question to add an an image from Kalen Delaney's book, there it says that they *are* sorted...

Comment: Sorry. I'm losing the will to live with this conversation. I don't know how many times I need to repeat the same point. The leaf level pages aren't **necessarily** sorted. They are only fully sorted if there is zero logical fragmentation

Comment: Fine then, thank you. You don't have to live with this conversation, I will just reward you for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an index, there is also an index table is created(I think its called Index allocation map (IAM), not so sure about the name)
In case of clustered index, the index table contains the index column, and pointer to the actual records.

So When a table has a clustered index, **data may not be physically sorted on the table**..
The data in the disk will be maintained as a linked list and clustered index is a pointer to that data.

Now the index table will be sorted physically... not the actual table..and the index table is maintained as a B-Tree, so that searching would be faster.

Now when you create a non-clustered index, it will point to the clustered index table

**Edit:** (as marc_s pointed out) Leaf node of clustered index actually contains data, where as in non clustered index contains pointers..

But still I don't believe, it will reorder the data in the disk, it will just reorder the pointers

Comment: So you mean to say that there will be two copies of the same data, one in sorted order in the B-Tree and another in order of insertion in the actual table? Won't that be grossly inefficient in terms of space?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: The index table will have only the columns, which are part of the index

Comment: Actually - the **leaf level** of the **clustered index**  ***IS*** the data.

Comment: @marc_s: when we insert a record to the table, will the leaf node be affected.. or the pointers to the leaf node?

Comment: The row will be inserted into the leaf level page, if there is enough space to hold that new row. If not - a page split will occur. And of course, the index pages above the leaf level will also be updated (with the new clustering key entry)

Answer (score 0):

Clustered indexes order the table data by the columns of the index. Each new row will be positioned in the right spot of the table when inserted or updated.

This doesn't happen with nonclustered indexes.

Answer (score -1):

**My original statement here is WRONG**
Because any index does **NOT** affect the data in the table at all. Clustered index is just another type of index **pointing** to data in the table. It does not change the order or does anything else to the data.
You can always fetch data directly from the table with row numbers before and after you create (clustered or unclustered) index.
**End of Original statement**

**Correction is required** (I don't use MSSQL very often, so never had a chance to test this before)
It seems that MSSQL implements clustered index as not really an index at all, but probably closer to trigger/constraint pair.

From my crude test right now:

1)

```
CREATE TABLE testTable ...  
INSERT ... (few rows)  
SELECT * FROM testTable
```

This shows ALL results in insertion order

2)

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ... ON testTable (...); 
INSERT ... (few rows)  
SELECT * FROM testTable
```

This shows ALL results ordered by fields in `CLUSTERED INDEX`
3)

```
DROP INDEX (CLUSTERED INDEX Name) ON testTable;
INSERT ... (few rows)  
SELECT * FROM testTable
```

This shows ALL results from step 2) [before `DROP INDEX`] **in the same order** and rows inserted later [in step 3)] in insertion order again.

To me it means that MSSQL **DOES** re-order the actual data records (most likely at great cost on insert/delete).

So, I stand corrected and rebuked.  In all honesty I never expected this (CLUSTERED INDEX behaviour, not me being proved wrong) to be the case.

Comment: So does a non-clustered index, how then does it differ from a clustered index?

Comment: But I have seen too many posts and too many books mentioning that it is not wrong, clustered index doesn't affect the way data is stored in tables!

Comment: Actually - the **leaf level** of the **clustered index**  ***IS*** the data.

Comment: @Germann It's ok, we all mistakes as we learn, but here, the moment you make a mistake, you will be penalized in the blink of an eye! No problem, thanks for your effort anyway...

Comment: @Cupidvogel I don't mind being corrected - it helps me learn... Some times assumptions are very misleading - as they can lead **you** in the wrong direction.