# Python SQlite ORDER BY command doesn't work

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

i just started out with programmming and wrote a few lines of code in pyscripter using sqlite3.

The table "gather" is created beforehand. i then select certain rows from "gather" to put them into another table. i try to sort this table by a specific column 'date'. But it doesn't seem to work. it doesn't give me an error message or something like that. It's just not sorted. If i try the same command (SELECT * FROM matches ORDER BY date) in sqlitemanager, it works fine on the exact same table! what is the problem here? i googled quite some time, but i don't find a solution. it's proobably something stupid i'm missing..

as i said i'm a total newbie. i guess you all break out in tears looking at the code. so if you have any tips how i can shorten the code or make it faster or whatever, you're very welcome :) (but everything works fine except the above mentioned part.)

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("gather.sqlite")
cursor1 = connection.cursor()
cursor1.execute('Drop table IF EXISTS matches')
cursor1.execute('CREATE TABLE matches(date TEXT, team1 TEXT, team2 TEXT)')
cursor1.execute('INSERT INTO matches (date, team1, team2) SELECT * FROM gather WHERE team1=? or team2=?, (a,a,))

cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM matches ORDER BY date")


connection.commit()
```

Comment: It's a little unclear to me what exactly the issue is.  It is that the INSERT is working but SELECT * FROM matches ORDER BY date is not?

Comment: Are you actually populating the date column? I don't see it.

Comment: also it will sort it as strings not by date since you specified it was TEXT .... you will also need `results = cursor1.fetchall()` after you do your select ...

Comment: @deakolt  the issue is that the command "SELECT * FROM matches ORDER BY date" works in sqlitemanager, but it doesn't work if i run it in pyscripter.

Comment: @JamesThiele    yes, i do populate the date column with "INSERT INTO matches (date, team1, team2) SELECT * FROM gather WHERE team1=? or team2=?, (a,a,)"

Comment: @JoranBeasley Beasley  it's not real dates, it's just numbers. And as i said. it works just the way i want it, if i try this command in sqlitemanager. 

 where exactly would i have to put the "results = cursor1.fetchall()" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I understand your problem.  First of all:  I'm not sure if that commit call is necessary at all.  However, if it is, you'll definitely want that to be before your select statement.  'connection.commit()' is essentially saying, commit the changes I just made to the database.

Your second issue is that you are executing the select query but never actually doing anything with the results of the query.

try this:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("gather.sqlite")
cursor1 = connection.cursor()
cursor1.execute('Drop table IF EXISTS matches')
cursor1.execute('CREATE TABLE matches(date TEXT, team1 TEXT, team2 TEXT)')
cursor1.execute('INSERT INTO matches (date, team1, team2) SELECT * FROM gather WHERE team1=? or team2=?, (a,a,))

connection.commit()

# directly iterate over the results of the query:
for row in cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM matches ORDER BY date"):
    print row
```

you are executing the query, but never actually retrieving the results.  There are two ways to do this with sqlite3:  One way is the way I showed you above, where you can just use the execute statement directly as an iteratable object.

The other way is as follows:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("gather.sqlite")
cursor1 = connection.cursor()
cursor1.execute('Drop table IF EXISTS matches')
cursor1.execute('CREATE TABLE matches(date TEXT, team1 TEXT, team2 TEXT)')
cursor1.execute('INSERT INTO matches (date, team1, team2) SELECT * FROM gather WHERE team1=? or team2=?, (a,a,))

connection.commit()

cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM matches ORDER BY date")

# fetch all means fetch all rows from the last query.  here you put the rows
# into their own result object instead of directly iterating over them.
db_result = cursor1.fetchall() 
for row in db_result:
    print row
```

Comment: that works. tanks. but how would i get it to save this new order to the database itself?

Comment: See my edit below. You basically cannot save an order to the database, but you can create it in order.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `commit` before the `SELECT *` (I'm not sure 100% that this is an issue) You then just need to fetch the results of the query :-) Add a line like `res = cursor1.fetchall()` after you've `execute`d the `SELECT`. If you want to display them like in sqlitemanager, add

```
for hit in res:
    print '|'.join(hit)
```

at the bottom.

**Edit**: To address your issue of storing the sort order to the table:

I think what you're looking for is something like a clustered index. (Which doesn't actually sort the values in th table, but comes close; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213721/how-are-the-table-data-stored-when-it-has-a-clustered-index)).

SQLIte doesn't have such such indexes, but you can simulate them by actually ordering the table. You can only do this once, as you're inserting the data. You would need an SQL command like the following:

```
INSERT INTO matches (date, team1, team2) 
    SELECT * FROM gather 
    WHERE team1=? or team2=? 
    ORDER BY date;
```

instead of the one you currently use.

See point 4 [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=PerformanceTuningWindows), which is where I got the idea.